# Is there a way to search through a string in json

Tags: c#, json

I'm trying to find Fortnite and return fortnites appversion and path. I dont know if the user is gonna have other apps/how many/what they are. I'm trying to do this in C#. I've tried looping through all of the InstallLocations but the user may have alot.

```
{
    "InstallationList": [
        {
            "InstallLocation": "E:\\Epic Games games\\Dauntless",
            "AppName": "Jackal",
            "AppVersion": "1.6.2.271281"
        },
        {
            "InstallLocation": "C:\\Program Files\\Fortnite",
            "AppName": "Fortnite",
            "AppVersion": "++Fortnite+Release-16.30-CL-16163563-Windows"
        },
        {
            "InstallLocation": "E:\\Epic Games games\\rocketleague",
            "AppName": "Sugar",
            "AppVersion": "BC2_Update34 CL 324887"
        },
        {
            "InstallLocation": "C:\\Program Files\\Spellbreak",
            "AppName": "Newt",
            "AppVersion": "release.13106-7085"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Define 'a lot'.  10, 100, 10M ?  I wouldn't worry about load times or memory usage until you hit 1000s.   Copy the JSON to you clipboard, Paste Special->Paste JSON as Classes, and boom, dead easy to deserialise into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome Gray Playz

I assume you worry about performance in your post. Performance should be considered in relation to the machine and environment you are running your program. I assume further you run your C# program on a gamer PC. Gamer PCs tend to have quite powerful processors. Even a ten year old gamer PC should parse JSON data alike the example with one thousand entries in less than a second. Looping through the array and comparing the strings should also take less than a second with the same data source. One thousand installed apps on a PC is rarely met I assume. Yet the performance of the naive implementation is adequate to the task.

If the naive implementation does not meet your performance requirements: consider using a dictionary datastructure where the key is the AppName and the value is an object containing at least the corresponding InstallLocation and AppVersion. Dictionary data structures are called HashMap or BinaryTreeMap in some languages. Then you should handle saving the information in an adequate format so you do not need to parse the JSON data again, which will hit your performance problem again. Performance problems often require a good understanding of data structure theory and computer machine internals. For the your problem domain this is probably over engineering, because the naive implementation is easy to implement and maintain and suits the performance requirements.

Write your programs with the KIS (Keep It Simple) principle

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do better than going through all the items in terms of computational complexity without having to use complicated data structures, so just loop through all the AppName.

Comment: TBH a collection of items that has 3 properties is hardly 'computationally complex'.

Comment: @Neil I am talking about the computational complexity of the algorithm (e.g., O(n), O(n log n) )., I am not talking about the problem beign complex itself.

Answer (score 0):

I realised how dumb this question was. "Performance" lol. Anyway if anyone needed the fix i just ReadAllText from the file. Deserialized it,  made a foreach for the InstallationList if the var = Fortnite and did var.AppVersion.ToString();